How can I define and use custom data types?
I'm trying to learn this very obscure programming language called Whisper. It's a minimalist language created for embedded systems, and I've been trying to get the hang of it. However, I'm having some issues defining and working with custom data types.
Here’s what I’ve gathered so far about the syntax:
Variables are declared using let (like in JavaScript, but it’s not a direct copy).
There are only four primitive data types: int, float, bool, and char.
Custom types seem to be defined with the type keyword, but I’m not sure how to structure it correctly.
I tried something like this:
type Point = struct {
    x: int
    y: int
}

But I’m getting a syntax error when I try to run it.
Has anyone worked with Whisper before? Can you point me in the right direction?
Specifically, I want to:
Define a simple struct-like custom type (like the Point above).
Create instances of that type and access the members.
Maybe even add basic methods or functions that work with these types.
Thanks in advance! Would really appreciate any insights or examples.
I’ve read through the Whisper documentation (as much as there is of it), and there’s nothing on defining complex types beyond the basics.
I also tried checking out the source code for a few open-source Whisper projects, but they mostly use the primitive types.
I experimented with basic "let" assignments, loops, and conditionals, which work fine, so I know my environment is set up correctly.
Any help would be appreciated!
